# Конвертировать php+html в js+html

Tags: php, html, jquery

```html
<form class="uk-form uk-form-controls uk-form-controls-text " data-uk-margin>

  <div class="uk-grid">

    <?php for($x=0;$x<40;$x++){ $a=m t_rand( "1", "20"); $b=m t_rand( "1", "20"); $znak=( ($a>= $b) and ($a+$b
    <40) and ($a-$b>=0))? "-":"+"; print '

      <div id="form" class=" uk-form-controls-condensed uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-small-1-2 ">
        <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="' .$a.'" value="' .$a.'" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
        <input type="text" id="znak" placeholder="' .$znak.'" value="' .$znak.'" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
        <input type="text" id="b" placeholder="' .$b.'" value="' .$b.'" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
        <input type="text" placeholder="=" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
        <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="" value="" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center">
      </div>


      '; }; ?>
  </div>
</form>
```

[пример](http://lenina44.ru/m/)

Comment: Если уж решили смешать всё в кучу. То используйте для этого хотя бы http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var template = $('.row');
var form = $('#form');

function fillRow($element) {
 var a = ($element.find('[data-a]'));
 var operator = ($element.find('[data-operator]'));
 var b = ($element.find('[data-b]'));

 a.val(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
 b.val(Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1));
 operator.val((a > b && a + b < 40 && a - b >= 0) ? '-' : '+');
}

fillRow(template);

for (var x = 1; x < 40; x++) {
 var newRow = template.clone();
 fillRow(newRow);
 newRow.appendTo(form);
}

$('input[data-result]').on('change', function() {
 var a = $(this).siblings('[data-a]').val();
 var b = $(this).siblings('[data-b]').val();
 var operator = $(this).siblings('[data-operator]').val();
 var result = $(this).val();

 console.log(a, operator, b, result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="uk-form uk-form-controls uk-form-controls-text " data-uk-margin>
 <div class="uk-grid">
  <div id="form" class="uk-form-controls-condensed uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-small-1-2">
   <div class="row">
    <input type="text" data-a class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
    <input type="text" data-operator class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
    <input type="text" data-b class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
    <input type="text" data-equal placeholder="=" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
    <input type="text" data-result class="field-result uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

А на PHP работать так должно

```
<form class="uk-form uk-form-controls uk-form-controls-text " data-uk-margin>
    <div class="uk-grid">
        <?php for ($x = 0; $x < 40; $x++): ?>
            <?php
                $a = mt_rand("1", "20");
                $b = mt_rand("1", "20");
                $znak = (($a >= $b) && ($a + $b < 40) && ($a - $b >= 0)) ? "-" : "+";
            ?>
            <div id="form" class="uk-form-controls-condensed uk-width-large-1-4 uk-width-medium-1-3 uk-width-small-1-2">
                <input type="text" id="a" placeholder="<?=$a?>" value="<?=$a?>" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
                <input type="text" id="znak" placeholder="<?=$znak?>" value="<?=$znak?>" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
                <input type="text" id="b" placeholder="<?=$b?>" value="<?=$b?>" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
                <input type="text" placeholder="=" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center uk-form-blank" disabled>
                <input type="text" id="result" placeholder="" value="" class="uk-width-1-10 uk-form-width-mini uk-text-center">
            </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
</form>
```